# JS and CSS not working properly after wordpress migration from subdomain

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have migrated my website from subdomain to root. I have modified home and siteurl in wp-options, connection to database in wp-config, used really simple ssl since I migrated from http to https and velvet blues update url to change urls.

Unfortunately js and css were not working properly both in admin area and frontend. I replaced wp-admin, wp-includes as well as theme files and plugin files with files from fresh wordpress, theme and plugin packages. That corrected most of the problems (although not all of them), but this seems to be caused by specific issue so I am looking for a more general solution which would correct both admin and frontend area.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: by not working properly I mean not working. E.g. when hover over admin menu submenus do not appear,  in theme section themes are not "in grid" next to each other, but rather below each other and obiously not formatted in usual way, etc. Hope this clears things a bit.

Comment: define "not working properly" so other users here can help you.